# Java Spring: Later loaded confgurations are ignored

Tags: java, spring, configuration

So I have an application that uses a local db.  This db is opened when the user inputs the correct login password.  Because of this, it makes no sense to have any dao's in my initial configs because the entitymanager won't be able to get a connection to anything.  To solve this problem, I have two `@Configuration` files, the `DefaultConfig` for setup and login, and the `AppConfig` for the authenticated loading of beans which loads all the persistence stuff.

The default config excludes certain packages, and only loads the ones needed initially.  In the `AppConfig`, I load the rest of the application's beans.

My thinking was that I could do

```
TheStaticContext.register(AppConfig.class)
TheStaticContext.refresh()
```

After doing that, when I listed the beans, I didn't see the rest of the beans loaded, instead, I saw AppConfig loaded in the same way as the previously loaded controllers.

I then went and told the `TheStaticContext` to scan some more packages,

```
TheStaticContext.scan("top.level.package")
```

And then I noticed the rest of the classes were loaded.  My question is, is there a better way to get my modular Config files loaded into the an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`?

I'm using  'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.1.RELEASE', 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.1.RELEASE' if that helps.

Any help is greatly appreciated.